# Windows 10 PC won't properly recognise iPhone

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, itunes, iphone

My iPhone will no longer properly connect to my PC. This started happening one day out of the blue.

- iPhone is connected via USB, vibrates and then shows charging symbol. It successfully charges.
- The trust computer dialogue appears on the phone, and I authorise it.
- The phone doesn't show in iTunes, or sometimes it does and after 1 second disappears.

---

### [image]

Apple iPhone appears in my drives list in Windows Explorer. It accurately shows how much storage space there is.

---

### [image]
[image]

If I go into the drive it correctly shows all the folders but they all contain nothing (I have thousands of photos on my phone that I need to transfer off).

---

### [image]
[image]

Except one folder, which shows a handful of images which I cannot open. I cannot import them via the Photos app in Windows. It just shows some blank images with no thumbnails. Once when I plugged in, this folder showed more photos than this, suggesting the connection maybe got lost very soon after connecting the phone.

---

### [image]
[image]

If I unplug the USB I get an error about it being disconnected, so it's definitely recognised.

---

### [image]

It's like the phone is connected at a basic level but cannot be used fully, or the connection is not fully and permanently maintained.

---

**I have tried**

- Different official iPhone USB cables.
- Different USB ports.
- iTunes is up to date.
- Windows is up to date.
- Reset the Privacy and Location settings on the phone, to force a reauthorisation of everything.
- Restarting the phone, restarting the PC, restarting iTunes.
- iPhone shows up in Device Manager under Portable Devices. The drivers are up to date. I've tried disabling and reenabling it.
- The Apple USB shows up under USB devices. The drivers are up to date.

---

### [image]

If I connect the phone to another Windows 10 laptop, the phone prompts me to allow it to access photos and videos (I don't get this on my PC) and I can successfully see all photos on my device when I explore the folders. This can't be a cable problem, but I'm not sure what else could be the problem with the PC itself.

Comment: Do you have the classical desktop or UWP version of iTunes?

Comment: @Ramhound Classic

Comment: Out of curiosity I would try the UWP version and see if that makes a difference.